# How to autofill form box value filling other one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a form in django using this class model:

```
#models.py

    class Example(models.Model):
        var_a=models.DecimalField()
        var_b=models.DecimalField()
        var_c=models.DecimalField()
```

Suppose that I have created a form using this variable:

```
#template.html

    <form id="example" method="post">
      <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" id="var_a" >
         {{form.var_a|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
     <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" id="var_b" >
         {{form.var_b|as_crispy_field}}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" id="var_c" >
         {{form.var_c|as_crispy_field}}
     </div>
```

Now I want to create a jQuery code that give me the possibility to autofill `var_c` when I insert value in the form box of `var_a` and `var_b`.

In particular I want to figure out the following equation:

```
var_c=var_a*var_b
```

Is it possibile to get it?

**Edit**

I have tried to use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('#var_a, #var_b').change(function (){
            var a = $('#var_a').val();
            var b = $('#var_b').val();
            $('#var_c').val(a*b);
          })
        });
```

But does not works. If I fill the box of form of `var_a` and `var_b` does not appear nothing in the `var_c` box form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#id_var_a, #id_var_b').change(function (){
    var a = $('#id_var_a').val();
    var b = $('#id_var_b').val();
    $('#id_var_b').val(a*b);
  })
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer. I have tried your code but does not work. I have edited my queestion following your suggestions.

Comment: check ids of your inputs using inspect elements

Comment: by default django adds `id_` before field names